Generating PDF from Rmarkdown?
I try to generate a pdf file using a code that have been working for more than 2 year. Now I get following error message:
! LaTeX Error: File `tabu.sty' not found.
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
Fejl: LaTeX failed to compile Double-programming_75MRR.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Double-programming_75MRR.log for more info.
Kørsel stoppet
I went to the link with no hope of solving it. Can anyone help?
updated packages
reinstalling tinytex

The tabu package is more or less completely broken. rmarkdown really shouldn't use this package! Check if your rmarkdown and pandoc versions are up-to-date and if yes, create a mwe and complain to rmarkdown/pandoc for using this package.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
